# CLion не видит компиляторов от cygwin

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, makefile, clion

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, все пакеты, необходимые для работы IDE, присутствуют.
Но...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавлю, что с Mingw всё работает.

Answer (score 1):

У вас не правильный путь к **cygwin**. Правильный будет `C:\cygwin64\bin`

Answer (score 0):

У вас всё намешано в одной папке, CLionу не только бинари нужны, так что скачайте отдельно с правильной структурой папок